# Event is sometimes null

Tags: c#, winforms, events, nlog

I'm having an odd intermittent issue that I can't seem to reproduce consistently.

I have a custom NLog target called NotifyTarget, shown below:

```
internal delegate void NotifyTargetEventArgs(string message);

[Target("NotifyTarget")]
internal class NotifyTarget : TargetWithLayout
{
    public event NotifyTargetEventArgs Notify;

    private List<string> _logs = new List<string>();

    public IList<string> Logs
    {
        get
        {
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(_logs);
        }
    }

    protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        string message = Layout.Render(logEvent).TrimEnd();
        _logs.Add(message);
        OnNotify(message);
    }

    protected void OnNotify(string message)
    {
        if (Notify != null)
            Notify(message);
    }
}
```

I have an application with a child form called `ErrorConsole` that attaches to `NotifyTarget.Notify`:

```
public partial class ErrorConsole : Form
{
    static NotifyTarget target;

    static ErrorConsole()
    {
        target = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName<NotifyTarget>("notify");
    }

    public ErrorConsole()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ErrorConsole_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadLogs();
        target.Notify += Log;
    }

    private void LoadLogs()
    {
        errorBox.AppendText(string.Join(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine, target.Logs));
        ScrollToLast();
    }

    private void Log(string message)
    {
        errorBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            {
                string prefix = errorBox.Text == string.Empty ? "" : Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
                errorBox.AppendText(prefix + message);
                ScrollToLast();
            }));
    }

    private void ScrollToLast()
    {
        errorBox.ScrollToCaret();
    }

    private void ErrorConsole_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        target.Notify -= Log;
    }
}
```

The `ErrorConsole` is loaded from a parent form (let's call it `MainForm`) after clicking a menu:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private ErrorConsole console;

    // ...

    private void errorConsoleMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (console == null || console.IsDisposed == true)
        {
            console = new ErrorConsole();
        }

        console.Show();
    }
}
```

Whenever I do encounter this issue, I can set a breakpoint after `target.Notify += Log;` and inspect `target.Notify` with the debugger to verify that the `Log` method is indeed being registered:

[image: Log is being registered to Notify]

However, if I put a breakpoint on `if (Notify != null)` and inspect `Notify` after continuing execution and triggering a log event, it appears to have been changed to `null` at some point:

[image]

When the application enters this "bad state", it persists for the whole session -- closing the form and trying again continues to fail, but restarting the application usually puts it back into a "good state".

What could be the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: Your method `ErrorConsole_FormClosing` detaches Log from the Notify event, Have you tried putting a breakpoint there to make sure that somehow it isn't being called more than you expect?

Comment: Why not move `target.Notify += Log;` to the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

You might have a rogue conditional breakpoint.

If you have one where you're testing for null, but the condition is

`Notify = null`

instead of

`Notify == null`

Then the breakpoint would be setting `Notify` to null rather than evaluating its value.

Comment: i got severely bitten by this last week

Comment: @pm100 I think it's happened to just about everyone who's used conditional breakpoints (me included). I still don't understand how the IDE allows it to happen.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the issue, as I've never even used conditional breakpoints before.